# Carrierwave and has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, carrierwave

I have Product model like this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :images, :class_name => 'ProductImage', :order => 'position DESC', :dependent => :destroy

def image_thumb
    images.first.image.thumb.url
  end

  def image
    images.first.image.url
  end
end
```

ProductImage model:

```
class ProductImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :image, :position, :product_id, :title

  belongs_to :product

  default_scope order('position ASC')

  mount_uploader :image, ProductImageUploader
end
```

Uploader model:

```
class ProductImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
...
 def default_url
  asset_path([version_name, "default.jpg"].compact.join('_'))
 end
end
```

But if I don't upload any image for product, I will get 'nil' in image_thumb and image methods. How get default_url if no one image uploaded and relation between Product and ProductImage models are one-to-many?

Comment: Of course I can manually check 'images.first' on nil and then, if true, set a default image. But it's variant not elegant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have access to an uploader, an uploader can't help you, so you have to do it by hand. You're already using a presenter (more or less), so this is extremely easy:

```
def image_thumb
  if images.any?
    images.first.image.thumb.url
  else
    asset_path("default.jpg")
  end
end

def image
  if images.any?
    images.first.image.url
  else
    asset_path("thumb_default.jpg")
  end
end
```

Similar code works for belongs_to relationships.

Comment: There's a more elegant solution.  In your Product class, change the thumb helper to: `def image() images.first.image || ProductImageUploader.new end` then in your view just call `product.image.url` and it will render the `default_url` you define if the image is null.

Answer (score 0):

What is the value you are getting for default_url?

Maybe the path is not evaluating correctly.

Try something like this (of course correct the path below to what it should be):

```
class ProductImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
   ...

   def default_url
      "/assets/" + [version_name, "default.jpg"].compact.join('_')
   end
end
```

Comment: No problem in the default_url method. Problem in 'images.first.image', because image.first return nil

Comment: If images.first returns nil that means the object does not exist altogether. You need to have some object for the default to work..

seems like your ProductImage instance does not exist, not only the image property